# Cell value = lastmodifieddate from hyperlink path

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Difficult to explain but my picture will make it clear.

My Excel sheet has hyperlinks in column a that links to the file for opening
but how to get the lastmodifieddate from that file in column l

Example : a22 is linked to file vimco, so what is the last modifieddate from that file has to come in l22

[the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msmo3.jpg)

> also not all rows in column a has hyperlinks and contains also a empty
>   or not linked cell so if that is so than nothing has to show in column
>   l it has to be blank if a is blank or not linked
>
> can it make a formula? so i type in cell =moddate and then shows the
>   date
>   is ok now

ok got the code now

```
Function GetDateTime(myCell As Range) As Date
    Dim myHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim Filename As String
    Application.Volatile
    On Error Resume Next
        Set myHyperlink = myCell.Hyperlinks(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not myHyperlink Is Nothing Then
        Filename = myHyperlink.Address
            'If it is a relative address insert this workbook's path
        If Not (Filename Like "\\*" Or Filename Like "[A-Z]:\*") Then
            Filename = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & Filename
        End If
        If Dir(Filename, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            GetDateTime = FileDateTime(Filename)
        Else
            GetDateTime = ""
        End If
    Else
        GetDateTime = ""
    End If
End Function
```

but now second thing if the link changes or I open my workbook or swap sheets is not updating the value of getdatetime - can that be fixed?

Comment: As far as I know, you'll need VBA to create an UDF that returns the last modified that of a file.

Comment: no matter how it is a way is good enough , yeah and also if i close the workbook and a week after i open again it keeps up last dates modified.      its a personel sheet so i copy that sheet to add a new personel in the warehouse

Comment: About calculation. check if calculation is turned to manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function in VBA, and use that in your Excel sheet.
For this,you need the `FileDateTime` function in VBA, to create something like this:

```
Function GetDateTime(r As Range) As Date
GetDateTime = FileDateTime(r.Hyperlinks(1).Address)
End Function
```

Now you can use this function as a normal Excel function and fill in the cell with the hyperlink as parameter. Like this: `=GetDatetime(A1)`. If there is a hyperlink in A1, it will return the date.

Comment: What have you exactly filled in in column I? Does the cell you are referring to contain a file hyperlink and if so, what does it point to? You can also add this line in the function: `debug.print r.Hyperlinks(1).Address`. What does it show in the Immediate Window?

Comment: i filled formula = GetDatetime(A38)   l 38 returns #VALUE!  still also if debug.print r.Hyperlinks(1).Address is added

Comment: the debug.print line will only show the hyperlink address in the Immediate Window of VBA. With that, you can check why the function can't find the date of the hyperlink address. The hyperlink address should be a filepath.

Comment: if i check hyperlink configuration its linked to C:\Users\bornt\Desktop\test.xlsx   the link is the correct

Comment: And you can also see that in the Immediate window?

Comment: Function GetDateTime(r As Range) As Date

GetDateTime = filedatetime(r.Hyperlinks(1).Address)
Debug.Print r.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function             if i do =GetDateTime(Cell) is now get 00/01/1900 in cell l

Comment: That is not the Immediate window. You can open the Immediate window with ctrl+G if you are in VBA. You can also check if the function works in a different way: instead of `r.Hyperlinks(1).Address` fill in `"C:\Users\bornt\Desktop\test.xlsx"` and check if you get an answer.

Comment: then r.hyperlinks(1).Address doesn't point to anything in that cell. Can you select cell A38, go to the immediate window and type `?ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.count` and press enter? What is the answer you get?

Comment: compile error invalid use of property     did checked the file and path is correct from hyperlink

Comment: Very strange.. because even if there are no hyperlinks, it should just say 0. How did you add the hyperlink to the cell?

Comment: i type text in cell right mouse klik, add link and i browse in my filepath and klik on te file that i want to link  then ok   you speak dutch Alex?

Comment: I do, but i'm not sure If I can help you any further because I don't understand why VBA can't see the hyperlink connected to your cell and why it gives that error when you try to count the number of hyperlinks.

Comment: This code from @AlexdeJong works perfectly for me, so you must doing something wrong. Could you please post an image of how do you create hyperlinks? Also, are you working on Windows or Mac?

Comment: i'm blocked can it be that  it is because i dont have FileDateTime function in VBA how to add   i have now code  that Alex told but not working                                           Function GetDateTime(r As Range) As Date
GetDateTime = FileDateTime(r.Hyperlinks(1).Address)
Debug.Print r.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function

Comment: Please, do not post code here. Edit original question and update it with the new info. Also, as I said in my last comment, you should post some screenshots of where you put this code, and how yo try to use it.